# PageRemote attribute doesn't send __RequestVerificationToken

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I'm using .NET 6 and razor pages.
`[PageRemote]` attribute in POST method doesn't send `__requestverificationtoken` to server and I get error 400.

This is my ViewModel

```
public class AddCategory
{
    [PageRemote(PageName = "Category", PageHandler = "CheckForTitle",
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    AdditionalFields = "__RequestVerificationToken",
    ErrorMessage = "This title is duplicate")]
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
 }
```

And this is my handler

```
public class CategoryModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public AddCategory Category { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public IActionResult OnPostCheckForTitle(AddCategory category)
    {
        return new JsonResult(category.Title == "a");
    }
}
```

`GET` method is ok and everything is fine, but in POST method `__requestverificationtoken` doesn't send to the server and I get error 400.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property that you are trying to validate is on a nested property. All fields listed in the `AdditionalFields` property will be prefixed with the nested property name when they are posted, so the request verification token will be posted as `Category.__RequestVerificationToken`.  As a result, the request verification token itself is not found, and request verification fails resulting in the 400 status code.

You should add a separate string property to the PageModel, `Title`, then apply the `PageRemote` attribute to that and reference it in the input tag helper via `asp-for`. Once you are happy that the submission is valid, you can assign the posted `Title` value to the relevant property in your `Category` object and process as usual.

```
public class CategoryModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public AddCategory Category { get; set; }
   
    [BindProperty, PageRemote(PageName = "Category", PageHandler = "CheckForTitle",
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    AdditionalFields = "__RequestVerificationToken",
    ErrorMessage = "This title is duplicate")]
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;

    public IActionResult OnPostCheckForTitle(AddCategory category)
    {
        return new JsonResult(Title == "a");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to define the Title property in the View model ?

Comment: @MiladAhmadi Updated the answer with an example

Answer (score 1):

@Mike Brind has been explained very nice. One way you can split the property from model and use `asp-for="PropertyName"` instead of nested property.

Another way is just override the name by specifying the name attribute like below:

```
<form method="post">>
    //if you use method="post", it will auto generate token
    //if you do not use method="post", remember add token like below
    @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@

    <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Category.Title"></label>
                                     //add the name....
    <input asp-for="Category.Title" name="Title" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Category.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
</form>    
@section Scripts
{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" integrity="sha256-v2nySZafnswY87um3ymbg7p9f766IQspC5oqaqZVX2c=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>        
}
```